# Dropdownlist "Enable true" is not working Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have set dropdown enable set to false in one button click and i will set enable="true" is not working in page load

here is my aspx

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJournal" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlJournal_SelectionChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="drop" />
```

Here is my click event:

```
 protected void btnTemplate_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        check.Value = "1";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "Load_functions()", true);


        //txtAddJournal.Attributes.Add("Style", "display:block");
        //btnUpload.Attributes.Add("Style", "display:block");
        //if (fileuploader.HasFile)
        //{
        try
        {
            string Filename = Path.GetFileName(fileuploader.FileName);
            //fileuploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + Filename);
            // fileuploader.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("D:\\Req Sep16\\") + Filename);
            OleDbConnection myconnectionini = default(OleDbConnection);
            OleDbDataAdapter mycommandini = default(OleDbDataAdapter);
            //if (fileuploader.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls") == false & fileuploader.PostedFile.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx") == false)
            //{
            //    // lbl_Error.Text = "Upload only excel format";
            //    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Upload only excel format');</script>");
            //    return;

            //}
            //else
            //{
            gvDetails.DataSource = null;

            string pathToSave = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadFiles/") + "Copy of Database_HBM";
            //fileuploader.PostedFile.SaveAs(pathToSave);
            //strFilePath = "D:\\Files\\" + fileuploader.FileName;

            string constrini = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" + pathToSave + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            // DataTable dt = new DataTable();        
            myconnectionini = new OleDbConnection(constrini);
            mycommandini = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", myconnectionini);
            ds = new DataSet();
            mycommandini.Fill(ds);

            gvDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            gvDetails.DataBind();

            ddlJournal.SelectedIndex = -1;
            ddlJournal.Enabled = false;

            //ddlJournal.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");


            //}

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }

        //}
    }
```

And my page load event is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Grid", "headerLock();", true);

        // ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Key", "<script>headerLock();</script>", true );
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Bindddl();
            BindGrid(null);
            ddlJournal.Enabled = true;

        }
        else
        {              
            ddlJournal.Enabled = true;

        }

    }
```

button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Template 1" OnClientClick="return Validate();"
                                    OnClick="btnTemplate_click" CssClass="btn" />
```

but still my dropdown list is disable.

suggest me get a solution 
thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to make the dropdown to hide or some thing else tell clearly?

Comment: I want to set Enable false when the button click event fires, otherwise it always enable true

Comment: @Bala I find it hard to understand 100% what you want, do you want the entire ddl to be enable false, so you cant click it, or is it the ListItems you want to be enable false, so you can see items but not click them?

Comment: Always the ddl is set to true only if the button click the ddl set to enable false.then i press f5 ie,page load my ddl not to enable true still it is enable false. what can i do now

Comment: Well this is very very confusing. How come you have `ddlJournal.Enabled = true` for both the `if` condition and `else` conditions? Isn't it supposed to be false in the `else` condition?

Comment: this is just my try only.but i put set to enable true in else part

Comment: So, you're saying that `ddlJournal` is always set as enabled, no matter what? Then what's the point in keeping them in the if-else block?

Answer (score 0):

You can set dropdown list Enabled false from its control only like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlJournal" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlJournal_SelectionChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="drop" Enabled="false"/>
```

And the rest code should work fine.

Please mark it helps

Comment: No,i don't want to set false default. only enable false in  that button click only,

Comment: so you can write code for the button click event, you have to check the condition for that event in the if else condition. Where is your HTML related code for button. Please paste that also

Answer (score 0):

Understand that your `if-else` condition in Page_Load() method is the main culprit. You're always setting `ddlJournal.Enabled = true`, no matter what. Seems like you didn't properly understand the concept of `IsPostBack`. `ddlJournal` is supposed to be disabled when `IsPostBack` is true, because that's what you want. Otherwise, it's supposed be enabled.

This is a very concise explanation about what `IsPostBack` is:

> Postback in an event that is triggered when a action is performed by a contol on a asp.net page.  for eg. when you click on a button the data on the page is posted back to the server for processing.IsPostback is normally used on page _load event to detect if the page is getting generated due to postback requested by a control on the page or if the page is getting loaded for the first time.

*[a comment from http://forums.asp.net/t/1115866.aspx?What+is+IsPostBack ]*

So based on that, you should change your code like the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Grid", "headerLock();", true);

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //When IsPostBack is false, ddlJournal should be enabled
        Bindddl();
        BindGrid(null);
        ddlJournal.Enabled = true;

    }
    else
    {
        //Else, IsPostBack is true, so, ddlJournal should be disabled              
        ddlJournal.Enabled = false;

    }

}
```

Also, you don't need this in your `btnTemplate_click()` method since you're doing this on page load:

```
ddlJournal.Enabled = false;
```